# I Am trying to understand how this translator code works i'm a beginner

Tags: python, syntax

```py
def translate (phrase):
    result = ""
    for l in phrase:
        if l.lower() in "aeiou":
            if l.isupper():
                result = result + "G"
            else:
                result = result + "g"
print(translate(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

This is a program for a simple fun translator, and I tried to understand how it works. The problem I am facing to
understand is the 6th line `result = result + "g"`.

1. How does it take the input value phrase and add it to the variable `result`?
2. How does it replace the vowels even when they're in the middle of the phrase?
3. What is the meaning of `result = result + "g"`?

The code changes the vowels from your input to the letter "g" or "G"

Comment: The expression `result = result + "g"` means, that you take your previous `result` and add `"g"` to that. Because you got strings that means you add the `"g"` at the end of your string. If your `result` is e.g. `"test"` and you make that operation than you basically do `"test" + "g"` and the new `result` is `"testg"`. And another thing is that the code you posted does not what you want it to do. It just replaces the vowels but doesnt keep the original characters and it doesnt return the `result` at the end of your function.

Comment: "I tried to understand How it works" Do you mean it is someone else's code and you are trying to understand how it works, or you wrote the code yourself and are trying to understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: Experiment with prints. It can answer many questions. For example, uou could add `print("before", result)` just before `result += g` and `print("after", result)` just after. Also `pinrt("next", l)` at the top of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code modified so it actually works as you intend.

```
def translate (phrase):
    result = ""
    for l in phrase:
        if l.lower() in "aeiou":
            if l.isupper():
                result = result + "G"
            else:
                result = result + "g"
        else:
            result = result + l
    return result

print(translate(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

input of `HELLO friend` produces `HGLLG frggnd`

As for the `result = result +'g'` line, the right side of an assignment statement is worked out first then assigned to the name on the left side. The code goes through the phrase letter by letter and either adds it 'as is' to results or changes vowels and adds the change.

Comment: I also have a suggestion that might help you, Copy and Paste the code into https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit and click Visualize to step through the code lines and watch what happens.